# MUI DataGrid Error: 'props.pageSize' cannot exceed 100 in DataGrid. How to display all rows?

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

It's a simple question, but seems that this functionality is purposely blocker by MUI.
How do I list 100+ row table in DataGrid without pagination? (not DataGridPro or DataGridPremium)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done while using a free version.
Like warning says:
"Only page size below 100 is available in the MIT version."